# Hyper-V Windows Server 2016 - Assign Public IP to Guest VM and allow internet access

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I'm setting up a Hyper-V (Win Server 2016) lab on a leased Dedicated Server.

The server has 2 (can get more) permanent IP addresses.

I want my Guest VM(s) to have full internet access, and use one of the permanent public IPs so I can RDP in and have them host web applications.

Effectively the Hyper-V host is just managing the VMs for replication / backup etc.

The host has a single NIC.

I have tried ICS (internet connection sharing) and I've tried setting this up as a NAT. So far the closest I have got is either full internet access through ICS but no routing of specific public IP traffic to my Guest VM or NAT routing control of RDP / HTTP traffic to my Guest VM but no external internet access available.

I've read so many tutorials and tried so many things I'm lost. Surely this should be much simpler than it is?

Comment: Have you tried the Remote Access Role which includes routing?

Comment: @Junaid is this different from RRAS with NAT enabled?

Comment: The old RRAS is called Remote Access Role in 2016 or at least thats my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same issue I was able to fix it in the end.. I spent a huge amount of time trying everything to get it to work..

It turns out because I was creating my Hyper-V lab on rented Dedicated servers I needed to get the provider to add my VM MAC Addresses to the IP address on their end. As soon as this was done everything just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested on 2016, but I manged to make this work on 2012 R2.

You will need to configure something called **IP Forwarding**: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962461.aspx

I have been able to do this follow steps from this link: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Windows_Server_2012_Subnet/en

Keep in mind that this is a very dirty solution and I'd generally against using it.